# Is there anything wrong with syntax of "for" loop in my list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

If this is correct

```
v = [22, 13, 45, 50, 98, 69, 43, 44, 1]
[ (x+1 if x >=45 else x+5)  for x in v ]
```

then what's wrong with this code?:

```
def isPrime(num):
is_prime = False
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break
    else:
        is_prime = True
else:
    is_prime = False
return is_prime


listTablesOnlyPrimes = [[ (i*num if isPrime(i*num)==True else pass) for i in range(1, 11)] for num in range(1, 11)]
for listTable in listTablesOnlyPrimes:
    print(listTable)
```

I want to know what's the `SyntaxError` in message by interpreter:

```
listTablesOnlyPrimes = [[ (i*num if isPrime(i*num)==True else pass) for i in range(1, 11)] for num in range(1, 11)]
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The ternary `if` operator requires an `else`.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a conditional expression, of the form https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

```
(x+1 if x >=45 else x+5)
```

But this does not fit that syntax because there's no else:

```
(i*num if isPrime(i*num)==True)
```

I believe that was intended to be an if condition as part of the list comprehension syntax, but that comes at the end, as described here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries

addendum:

not part of the question, but since you asked, here's a way to quickly add some unit testing to your code. Just put this right after your isPrime function

```
if not isPrime(11):
    raise ValueError("isPrime isn't right")
```

You do need a few more checks, but that is enough for now. I don't want to go into the whole unit test library.

Comment: I've actually tried that one as well but still ain't working. If you can share your working code script I will really be grateful.Thanks for replying sir.

Comment: That was the syntax error. Your isPrime function always returns false, but at least it's not a syntax error, which was the question. And the other numbers are all a product of two integers, so they have a pretty good chance to be not prime. A few of them actually should be prime like 1*7 for example, but useful trivia -- 1 itself is not prime.

Comment: There are plenty of other questions on how to test if a number is prime. You can look at those.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with if condition inside the nested list

```
listTablesOnlyPrimes = [[ (i*num) for i in range(1, 11) if isPrime(i*num)==True] for num in range(1, 11)]
```

**Note:**

> Your code always return empty lists I don't understand why are you doing this `i * num` never become prime if `i > 1`